# How to get a CouchDB _list result with Cradle

Tags: couchdb, cradle

In Node, using Express and Cradle, I have a call to a _list that does not work. Other calls go to _view and work fine. The [Cradle documentation](http://cloudhead.io/cradle) does not include a section on _list but it seems from [this GitHub readme](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle/commit/c4b7deb182a150a2f46696364c9b68c9fb56f852) that it is supposed to work just like _view.

My code looks like:

```
if(isList){
    db.list(couch_url, function (err, res) {
        if(err){
            console.log("error couchdb list", err);
        }else{
            //console.log(res);
            callback(JSON.stringify(res));
        }
    });     
}
```

The `couch_url` variable is just the regular http request and looks like: `myCouch/_design/Model3D/_list/convert/All` except the path designators (_design, _view, _list) have been removed to get `Model3D/convert/All` for Cradle (it looks like they are put back in the Cradle function). That full path represented by `couch_url` will work in other CouchDB connections, and like I said, the Cradle view function works fine.

The error object I get is:

```
{ stack: [Getter/Setter],
    arguments: [ 'ILLEGAL' ],
    type: 'unexpected_token',
    message: [Getter/Setter] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the list function you are using - it is highly likely to be producing broken JSON.
In my case, I was getting a result of 'undefined' for a property.  Anything undefined should be dropped, and all property names should be in quotes

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this, but it seems to work for me. Just double checking is "convert" your list function and "All" your view name?

The only other caveat I am seeing is that your database name has a capital case character in it. CouchDB databases must be all lowercase.

Comment: Jan - can you give me the couchdb and cradle versions you used successfully? There may be some rule about capitalization - but all my other couchdb-related calls work fine with that database name, so its hard to believe that would mess up just the _list function...

Comment: Also, the names are in proper couchdb order - I know it because if I use any of several other non-cradle routes (perl, curl), it works.